# Solutions for internationalization of a web application based on Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, i18next

I am looking for a solution how to get the web appliaction based on vue.js multilingual.
In my research I found i18next. Is this the best solution or can someone recommend me something else.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [Vue I18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/).

And here is the [Github repo](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n).

Comment: Thanks! Why do you prefer it?

Comment: `i18next` probably works fine but is a more generic solution. While `Vue-I18n` was specifically created for `Vuejs`. There is a whole ecosystem around it (see website navbar) and a lot of support from the community. So if you have a problem or a specific use case, you are more likely to solve it with `Vue-I18n`.

Comment: Do both have the same range of functions or are there differences?

Answer (score 0):

Vue-I18n is the best solution for adding internationalization to a Vue application. If you are looking at how to use it or how to get started with it here is a great article that shows you [how to add Internationalization to a Vue application](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-add-internationalization-to-a-vue-application-d9cfdcabb03b).

Comment: Why is it better than i18next? What is different to i18next?